# How To Get UIView Height Only?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code :

```
_width.text = NSStringFromCGRect(_screen.frame);
```

and it gives me on my iPod 5:

```
{{0,20}, {320,548}}
```

how to get only height value = 548 so that I can use it to calculate another components.

thank you.

Comment: `image.size.height;` or if a UIView `view.frame.size.height;` As a string `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", view.frame.size.height]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want a `CGFloat`, not a `NSString` if you want to calculate other components.

```
CGFloat height = _screen.frame.size.height;
```

Or if you want a string after all:

```
 _width.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _screen.frame.size.height];
```

---

The `frame` property of `UIView` is a `CGRect` struct. To learn about `CGRect` go take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGRect).

Comment: bro, your solution is working, but it gives me floating number : 548.000000, I'm expecting Integer 548. but I don't see there's CGInt on Xcode.

Comment: Why do you want an integer? Why don't you make your calculations with floats?

Comment: I''m going to use it to manipulate UITextView's height. isn't it integer?

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to use CGGeometry check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html), in your case use `CGRectGetHeight()`.

```
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(_screen.frame);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this...

You can get Height Like this...

```
CGFloat height = _screen.frame.size.height;
_width.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",height];
```

You can get Width Like this...

```
CGFloat width = _screen.frame.size.width;
_width.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",width];
```

You can get x coordinate Like this Like this...

```
CGFloat x = _screen.frame.origin.x;
```

You can get y coordinate Like this Like this...

```
CGFloat y = _screen.frame.origin.y;
```

Comment: This won't compile. `_screen.frame.size.height` is not a `CGRect`

Comment: @Desdenova Now i've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

_screen.frame is a struct with a `CGSize` and a `CGPoint`.

```
CGPoint origin = _screen.frame.origin;
CGSize size = _screen.frame.size;
```

The struct `CGPoint` has the members `x` and `y`

```
CGFloat x = origin.x; // float on 32bit and double on 64bit
CGFloat y = origin.y;
```

The struct `CGSize` has the members `width` and `height`

```
CGFloat width = size.width;
CGFloat height = size.height;
```

You can print a message with a formatted `NSString` or C-String with the format specifier `%`

```
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My screen height is: %f", height];
```

If you want to show the height as 543 not as 543.0, then use the float string specifier in the `NSString` creation method

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Integer height is: %.0f", height];
// even with values like 0.9999 the output would be "Integer height is: 0"
```

If the property _width.text is a `NSString`.

```
_width.text = output;
```

Comment: wow.. that's a very complete guidance, thanks's bro! but your solution also gives me Floating number as Albertamg has. while I'm expecting integer as value. because later on, I'm going to use it to set UITextView's height. Or maybe UITextView's height can accept floating number?

Comment: you will always get a floating number, but you can easily convert it to signed/unsigned int with casting: instead of CG float use int height = (int)size.height;, when you don't care about certain warning  you can of course assign a float to an int value, it will run without a problem (you will loose the precision behind the point with intention though, float 1.9f => int 1).

Comment: Oh now I understand, the NSString should not use any trailing values behind the point, edited my answer to reflect this.